Valid Username using java regex hackerrank question solve
This is a hackerrank question.
You are updating the username policy on your company's internal networking platform. According to the policy, a username is considered valid if all the following constraints are satisfied:
The username consists of  to  characters inclusive. If the username consists of less than  or greater than  characters, then it is an invalid username.
The username can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores (_). Alphanumeric characters describe the character set consisting of lowercase characters , uppercase characters , and digits .
The first character of the username must be an alphabetic character, i.e., either lowercase character  or uppercase character .
For example:
Username    Validity
Julia INVALID; Username length < 8 characters
Samantha VALID
Samantha_21 VALID
1Samantha INVALID; Username begins with non-alphabetic character
Samantha?10_2A INVALID; '?' character not allowed
Update the value of regularExpression field in the UsernameValidator class so that the regular expression only matches with valid usernames.
Input Format
The first line of input contains an integer , describing the total number of usernames. Each of the next  lines contains a string describing the username. The locked stub code reads the inputs and validates the username.
Constraints
The username consists of any printable characters.
Output Format
For each of the usernames, the locked stub code prints Valid if the username is valid; otherwise Invalid each on a new line.
Sample Input 0
8
Julia
Samantha
Samantha_21
1Samantha
Samantha?10_2A
JuliaZ007
Julia@007
_Julia007
Sample Output 0
Invalid
Valid
Valid
Invalid
Invalid
Valid
Invalid
Invalid
Explanation 0
Refer diagram in the challenge statement.
import java.util.Scanner;

class UsernameValidator {
   
    public static final String regularExpression = "^[a-zA-Z]{1,1}[a-zA-z0-9_]{7,29}";
}


public class Solution {
    private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        while (n-- != 0) {
            String userName = scan.nextLine();

            if (userName.matches(UsernameValidator.regularExpression)) {
                System.out.println("Valid");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }           
        }
    }
}

this is my code its run perfectly but when hackerrank run hidden test cases it show message test cases failed :(
test case:

100
q_O ds-BvRVa+T_AQ%gYQV[`ZTj;@qp|swgy!gr^{rs^w.r|1+\
z571SlRKL*6QAa#{b/IJk++X[e}NwB}
DAi6dBcNx'`v,hFh,Zj
zpc2au6}v_T
qeVh#S0'1T;gI/Vs>6C]L'Ohl&Ph?xI|~QGG\*^aOK";sc#"o<`@0f-6>lf ,u*y1CTb~&9Q*
ss:se}(Cm,+ I$}D%tV8lG YRJBHem?}m6S_2:3Q^'h}#n;OVfN"7G%\2u+e(.NCuxY]!48<\S&4HP~>n0HqtprB
f]A<tket1"C@#JRb%l
hhR3Dz> uc&iA,Zn;AsA4+Li7b0a"B:X|ag*|M!F=v"Bo"\:z(2Jos2ae^wspY\)LYl`xe$yY}9J8i0vpU`h@X"EhWA\hT*
e`lkbcXv7Jo8(87 <9^O<*4 l^6. 9dUMu~m!
c2wA<6]}R=)p@S'2$bVZ^>18P"O2$I9k.s$/s=4<nO){~Ufvh16xG7Rk2s;WB8:5N1)L{;-
NW(nE&Uv;BPoHI\~&cT)
l4w425jD15<n#h/BzE~Zp_{{t_zV<y#R)n<eQo}'ST=*iDdl*|N;u12RPs'>EI&aqQ"[Wl`T+'GZnD3"9bFM
$3)4Henl,>)=[(1a?F5yBm=XE|NscU`uRL>F?KXO?'s'7XM$P&c8n"BQV_2V<_#Sj>`BrF%DPi^c`D}2Rz>w.01IS943;x
"0hmPQ(xqeh.KrIsl,D^<oxJO0|`4bC'z>.PV'[PeeER{9VqH@aRS|E[f0,| _w=^tmje eR:vEPD$M^JI&3He4
/5vf``j/(yYf
S$bN?V4't'!K'i2e]@6Mel lUy>O$iCBeQt?K-_-<}yo$nzD!<Hzy{
0n];#B\X^#=~N}e^P.W1'+Rj<i7)YCTa.ZzePn8Ko)c&ySNxN`L^pSC7MqkvJSL3[k-R]7v):Zhd$/iY~C,P2
kK%sjL>`>xvdxrsgI][[Aun^\g"2+)6k=]_ffu9C9%lGJ{lI.BwC^I#E@i%[L?sSr<nZw&Ysx^1&JSb{.CvbDfdNcU`*q!^$
E{<u))%kt^`di~NSWTDN]$4RUs{uB
a}+\8V\gdhXRn8o_/^FyP%]_L~M#Kua|V_lYHAm,\fX{a)%BznZp|$69>#=K`hH"th
3U!TYd~o8)nOxdp#xvuLYwOogX,G;aHGbs"Cu6sp7I0#6HSWrDGlxMG<BsJ[|BCo0rg'uZp]&,D Ypa94XsQU
H/hhlkMbM.Z4CH^2Dn;TK~9\WM.ycZR;/29?i^p\nX![rNG%b99}/<
N[lhoa=Y5))Vk{Si+_VY okg`}EN0/Tp@FnT@s5in`^4fLo+>w4JL]K
f!^gji,QnArc~x@_g-g(y.XsuxTk(~q?]zgKCY*pJ@_p"I1H_^ll]|\
$u@`IyWL.efmb;I3g|#O3-O*hF"PIE|"XpQ7?=Yart1N*?3NZqzeA/9!nJxV2w%KJd>n=o(cZf<eMev!bY=t0-#p"$^4h~M s ]
A'PUDXD"9,GSoyY9X4/}@.0~QNDYO@!OpB?B}0T*Q>]L/Q>+sC!tBTEgChS4tBjco(\~c#Qx^*Sa^0[l':{|;
j?9H;ImC_;`l lz QTzt%E+}Eevx2dI'GEHc;l2;n4x@ `{ulGtA``Fg'gG
W] \4p19\BWo{yvq[n&|[*LS#D
|XMh=35Llrcvu|<h
vQdFG&Z]\~
+dK7/E5M0"S6IC@#LH`PY:3#n| `S8]Z(FKGeCak#7,K.Q7_1#wiGi?)!\B}ryh5>
]1j+0N#n
!AQ'Sl`Skf1LrYV\DVfwU
W&Hk[R_Jv~.rnTpkR|Ihop/@fU;2jp&D:v`1;[q(4>4J?%\)":pbTPYh77l:
Axekv<K+B<+`1Q#sU|y+57:/ *WISA9`}sAqPxs"}\N-n5T+si'FHz`^BQpWBtph
P??.4n?uK@ms"pUQqr^skhQ:g+G,E4AH$YR=jCzG{p2zcP8 /ivmY_#ySNq \7fM.uq(rvk
0kP]DSWfu^S@/#[gB/UuO=#@XNg>y(]~VI* :AP
/gsGsQ<p(RQfK"3ohF"(pvbKLt$TK]$`^d58.Ii>>qhK"Q,/mtx4Mi33Z%"i=aW<b;;k,'gV5?4sKGVN-I,!#?
uzP,pdtC?Z`qmyaC2W;EoGzBr52(&'jlwSa5PrRUcEq.<!zUSS/1B#^oVj)J(tK2awS!xZ
hcAPbk=fae_zyC|R99|@Q484Pp1fHqmT/'{B#1rP$Y
*cL}t1[J9Vvog0k9vq[ FP)JHI6Y<9z7*hY!pJ/9Q
>`D\X=YD|YKn7Zyner\Ew+\gJSr9D~3RmyUR#ur@j;W^n{`T9YOBTz.fw.e{Ow?w6wypL+U
n]J=3muNZv,DlK/g5B"/MZH
3JIY3Ue\+8p,EYQDg}=)i
uk+vJ+w',==NP8(d:%(r]KDM7fg>w0o%14F,-6CP%I2W,ga4hHQa+M4JC-OGN3?R)~!z7o@Qz
]jbr*|+C7T(QZS,^WFE?*OoBUy9 T0d\J=HObc`'$=AnN
`cRv:=Oq/3=~Q8UX}L&u:>fN2`db_`Ow;*}[qm,M:x8zfAN;ngoz Fap0^r?N)pvz4
(A=wIIZn+Ud^8N(K$:ehrlqU$H'W8i<C},b4TkicwF_h@gu_.}#0*
u]CvW^R'h;NTjEe-H^h
4K6q_BG5D0AmCr/Z\ZFu%z\L7D9 vMO9XNJx=7E/'N<;|<8b8!`V5=3V*8ME{jxH;TSD8^,
~0~vM<.'@BiTV
Ak5kwQD pC#3H-!_av}bbG_FsW8>5kqT{T?^i/~[M,Z:K"daUY@&8Ik_MYJom-P-QuTrrV"XWCBk;}
Q<g$dt[}R8q4tjrk\5|j|\}gVEcWxLb>yHtJR>N:`=6o#\Gm0A%6BLj)(b<sdzHuw"3n99tFbxq6H9p
\g6(#QOy.<nfmrNFQ1Jua'>'M|R8+biQnyb
98,~[Sij2^%A}!LvgBV
'"Hj|sj$ZNwS$2?Fb5VJ"u[9%Z+Nb3{iab?dI&MKgdQa0At^k(_{OCrt
=[BR\wY^S)>mprQej#MLX|=enyy{4sS/&cRhmp8z
9CZgn93: *|UPb@O$dl ;d1qwRFX%`Fi`nl&2+iXIm2)~^b=>bv4|q]fX$Q^;OR\|UC=`5[s;KQ"Y@~*p'$/YdqL|9<'c`@A90`b
>BzM]lH@IzHzM47_kVsa~bH[(qql^qjd"!V0Lg-$
VMc^Un1L43PIm4|@;izr3V v"8O(3hSo{94c@(
MXJuj{mRoo6t:qJ21avQz)-|CFKcMX&W
lZcN2l{S(|W =C,X(Td?rj|{L"d6iV*K%E6(w5+o4NlV0\G8q[U0NM65hK4w|.g#A3*,}1{`{[|Wg=<4UeFR559R+XIp]r
^pb7Rf6_ey`{w9bm\UAiI*~BB 1 qYo~N2y6VZ_3F%;)
4I>Mpzw`i"V<PLoBEP
W:2b#|I+q&=HeZ '^#}$ n\Oqi(5G,ovo3{t&<@H2AJ]x7\tch~O/Iax-`s?xa$"}YvN'eu5GT(H)S94Fwxbif,1sVP6Kw}
N-iN8cM8nYlHk(u*_B`X6RdR0I6r<*nXfrQT"!3&!%']H"IE`ZS;7BD3ga[q^lVGI5Q_AO:A5e$WCNI(L#Ibl*8kO7AI4CJ$I
7uajIi&n]sB!{+x{~<jWdU
@"A\VN0o.I5*Jc:(KU
C^"w0N]hVsgA0)z>nFQY{%MR3?74Sur^Z
nrWdvRoc X9'hYDU.AQavrUZYQu]'Bk#}s:pF<6&]D%+?T:)+wKq;7IVGh$Tt
\whyPpt+ZmFA\tCzgf:Atbzb30?}~Z8`4jiMCv(2{b=R8qg~c^EAk*wl1`hLpigJH8*+33h3$!CzBMaJVkI)8O(tspuR
2D&\4Pc*;t=HsTxk/,s8}i^FCaE;#T8Pp_4@>d=>[YrXUbIT",CXeO'%ufSh4D@;NrXA$>lj?9prbeT[!Z
:A,`KZ:QkPrXSsN1\@U=}T{|4l85)I7G@2[oooRc?;H $\h8.Rj;M%XbBm J]4Tbka<[mc%7C\728*e]@A{)/w'YNS^d:)n<9
(oXSoUMHn=1hP!-1Zvh"5U.t2u\yg.cJnx'%wp(}bRm(O+m_sg:}n=l.k(jxEa*OPIn^6ZK\:=hZpe`
D/]D}cBobsasi:P_?i=&CME ZDaGxc?4cj1sli]HIQQ9C1.9id_,wFCByjSwz)\YE: yYQp4'9+9y4n>XQTn^
*SAXT<A(>H(f[u>le)KB2nMbdbA/9yDO`_K(_u9
WgOkatNG^
z^PfllyE@S2Age@+i_1YgSr*LNq>yCIyb|<l%26Be!A0{.ljG8Z^Ulu4/Y.Z-LfHTXl2h]'fYef@4p?
hcSDigeoqIrSK0!>5&A,S#6E"#\)L\SbB6*&jvZa_Z3u" =$K)f>':SG-KWPSjc1n-U`FvhZL ySd1"`MUWsF"!S
Y<>BcN.fbMO//vrcoTK#.jz^@>uIf(]k\ex!a9@;P
TXUZLPN82jK~,o~JGR/)Zal*W8T);fub.>_$P:*{eclWlW]fctk;/07IarNHI"nbegR]7R/Vl!)!0WT~pji[O^G-`FZR.{C]
,Z|4U'jRS/fps+X7zc@>d.}RHreld-#C+;H/t4|_(<5$eY^tYJyDy7n<GX\}^U*4@K"9hW>=4~9@uQUv1<t<G9b3P]\K7sW>*}.
(+<.(V5GJ+7`a\UMdMi-}N
n:!_K^UpG~z0axi4rm6^:9_nkY<%W%53#~l[lv~"^
eJpvu:jM@Sg&0|fTN0sU?r` BjT$ 1wK(jz#WcQ\<UR\DL(>]#N)OeK-YUT*RtA>qC
yOlMdMv)-4U`'ed'HbuEkCHL%xe(z){ww*YVyH|#nVzaR
0a&8+R|V=il_F0|{t`uh|!\^)XF/{Z7E|<-0oArjjhA#{TjK?R{m<r;M>~d8u b~2dqmXg.,C_SH?"5p\(k*
r4kk p3?9B2*_T_qZC@Gq*1U?d.eZ=[4U(pmc$E!I.HfZ[u,,0MUtyRW n1upu/2G5ev'G`)l:pa|
M}i@fV"c`'pwVA.SK:ih-T^rL =['J-8APcp+>oy{SQ(fhUr&kFd?zBoAaLfU4dMG^(u=?"[2Z{Gm#+{h4&
fWRZ+103i7hAR-h. 5K\1Gjkp.C d& "9H|n0D2A
+D"B!9iI:cRr#SODJ{SM86KZkGe.Z#04gMe?xxd)2+zZlld0@`.6R1!xs[Q5&[/SjNSA`w
+`56.T.@EU;k8b@CCFJP6]e q(J,{-[>@m7:p 9tJ/7D+~`qXd~{hpE^^fKq,{7ji2tG
Y]giPcTl8M
U5D@ -fi&sK[v}CaZc uud2%[CF-;6o-'zL`"F{T4St;AD3o @1$-Vja9U:er4xrxdx+)VziqBD
MQCuWy$W%uhl,`pz>?JfH
4pD)QU@la4dT-d34h%1V-]AA<7z&o0PusLG9s;TwR"|>0l'C^}ZItV3GI75z*CB']x[rcpJ~E>qccGl IWayf8%zt]'<)A.e
Oa;ln1VtE{~@#q*-qv?!}._7]BrNVW2r2\)_38r,X=]+n6~MBp(> q;mVE)[y<Y/M}7!20sb`q-<^%*qfT%ZG;N!2Q&zEPd`
Iz4t=O%-9msOMnj6 +`m4OG<]:}|
R0zf*s6|MKMZNa
UDYD.cl9Zy8/L",*#DHvR

expected answare:
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid

[A-z] matches more than just letters.

The close reason is wrong. The correct close reason is 'typo'. In this case, OP wrote A-z which explains why their program does not work; A-z here isn't intentional. It's a typo. In the linked-to 'duplicate', it was 'intentional', with the intent for that to match all of A-Z as well as a-z, which is does, but it also a few more characters, such as the caret.
